# I have no hard drive am running UBUNTU 14.1 live from the USB thumb drive

Tags: live-usb, persistence

If I download any Ubuntu add ons  such as ubuntu-restricted-extras package 
where will they be stored?
I am just using ubuntu to go online and view some windows Excel programs that I download ,alter and upload again to the cloud
Ubuntu  works great for all of this
I shut down the computer, no hard drive to infect
I am often prompted to install addins for enclosed videos
I am worried that they will be installed on
and damage the Ubuntu Boot USB flash drive
Do I need to Partition the Flash Drive?
Add another flash drive? How will it know to install them there?
Or is the computer's Ram enough to store them
If so How?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You would have had to have made a persistence file on your USB flash stick in order for packages and documents to remain on your flash stick after each use. I believe it's stored in a file called squashfs and its contents are only accessible to Ubuntu when it boots up.